# How to export a c++ code with a template to Unity?

Tags: c++, templates, dll, unity-game-engine, extern

Lately Ive been trying to export some c++ codes to Unity3D trough DLLs and it has been working great so far! But, and there is always a but, now I need to export a code that contains a template and this seems to annoy Unity as it will promptly display me a EntryPointNotFoundException error message. Ive done some googling and wasnt able to find much info about this. Is it possible to export a c++ templated class to Unity via DLL? How ?

This is the .h code:

```
#define EXPORT __declspec (dllexport)

extern "C++"
{
    void __declspec(dllexport) computeMinBox3D(int numPoints, void* points, float epsilon, void* resultPoints);
}
```

This is the .cpp code:

```
template <typename Real>
void computeMinBox3DAux( int numPoints, void* points, float epsilon, void* resultPoints )
{
//...
}
```

And this is the code Im using at Unity:

```
 [DllImport("MinOBB_DLL.dll")]
        private static extern void computeMinBox3D(int numPoints, IntPtr points, float epsilon, IntPtr resultPoints);

    public void createOBB()
    {
                int numPoints = 9;
                float[] points = new float[numPoints];
                float[] resultPoints = new float[24];
                Vector3[] result3DPoints = new Vector3[8];
                float r = 1.0f;

                for ( int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++ )
                {
                    points[i] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-r, r);
                }
                int rangesArraySize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(float))* numPoints;
                IntPtr pointVec = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( rangesArraySize );
                Marshal.Copy (points, 0, pointVec, numPoints);

                int resultArraySize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(float))* 24;
                IntPtr resultVec = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( resultArraySize );

                computeMinBox3D( numPoints, pointVec, 0.01f, resultVec );
    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: maybe you have to explicitly instantiate it?

Comment: Use C code only to cross the Mono/native boundary. No C++ allowed to ease linking.

Comment: I guess you are right.. I couldnt find a way to use C++ for ease linking, so I ended up not exporting this method. =/